# How can I take multiple elemtents in a list comprehension

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

I want to take five consecutive primes generated as an infinite list by `primes` and check them if they summed make another prime. I want to have something like this:

```
consecutivePrimes = [ a+b+c+d+e | a:b:c:d:e <- primes, prime a+b+c+d+e]
```

This `a:b:c:d:e <- primes` however doesn't work and I can't find any way as to get multiple elements at once in a list comprehension.

Comment: I'd love to hear some feedback on my question/answer and why a close vote was given?

Answer (score 3):

Since a list comprehension can be thought of as a `map` combined with a `filter` (at least for lists), you can only get one element at a time inside of it.

But you can still do this by making `primes` into a list of lists using `tails`, then taking 5 elements from each of the lists. The single element you map over (`ps`) in this case is a list.

```
import Data.List (tails)
consecutivePrimes = [ a+b+c+d+e | ps <- tails primes, let [a,b,c,d,e] = take 5 ps, prime a+b+c+d+e]
```

Pattern matching on the list of 5 elements will always succeed if your input list is infinite.

Comment: Upvote by me, all tough I am not a big fan of using `let` in list comprehensions.

Comment: You could also do `a:b:c:d:e:_ <- tails primes` and then you don't need the `take`.

Comment: @DavidFletcher that's the answer I'm looking for. Please add that as a solution to my question so I can accept it.

Answer (score -1):

This is my solution which works but I find it quite ugly:

```
consecutivePrimes = [x | x <- consecutivePrimes' primes, prime x]
consecutivePrimes' (a:b:c:d:e:xs) | prime (a+b+c+d+e) = (a+b+c+d+e) : consecutivePrimes' (b:c:d:e:xs)
                                  | otherwise = consecutivePrimes' (b:c:d:e:xs))
```